# Linguistic Use of Spanish Characters Keyboard Layout

Tags: gramática, lingüística, símbolos, keyboard

After looking at the Spanish Keyboard that comes in Windows I have come to notice that there are 5 Dead Keys on the Spanish Keyboard layout.

```
  Name                Example 
´ ACUTE ACCENT        más
¨ DIAERESIS           pingüino 
` GRAVE ACCENT       
ˆ CIRCUMFLEX ACCENT 
~ TILDE
```

Why do such dead keys exist on the keyboard layout?

What significance do they have in the language?

Comment: In older keyboards tilde did not appear. It had to be written with ALT+126. It's been probably added because in programming and the Internet is quite common.

Comment: @MikMik Interesting, but still doesn't explain why their is a dead key though

Answer (score 6):

`` ` `` (grave accent) is there for [Catalan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_language#Writing_system). For this language, the `ç` and the `·` were also brought in (at least on the physical keyboards sold in Spain).

`^` is likely to be used for completeness (this accent is quite common in Portuguese and French)

Comment: `^` and `~` are used in reintegrationalist Galician orthography, so all of the keys (dead or not) in a "Spanish" keyboard layout can be used in some (co-)official language of Spain.

Comment: PS "Brought" is the past form of "bring" in standard English.

Comment: @PeterTaylor facepalming myself right now... thanks!

Answer (score 1):

~ TILDE   año, niño

GRAVE ACCENT and CIRCUMFLEX ACCENT are used in Portuguese, I think.

Comment: Are there any other letters in the Spanish language that use the tilde? There is already a separate key for ñ, so I'm trying to figure out if there might be another reason why.

Comment: I doubt there's some good reason (except perhaps some back-compatibilty thing) that explains why ~ ^ ` are dead keys in the spanish keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

The acute accent is used to mark which is the stressed syllable.

The diaeresis is actually only used in the 'u' letter. It is used to note that it must be pronounced in contrary to the normal uses of the ‘gue’ and ‘gui’ in the Spanish language.

There are no uses in Spanish (that I know, maybe some obscure reference) for the grave accent and the circumflex accent.

As you say, the tilde is only used for the letter 'ñ' in spanish and no other letters uses it. I have sometimes seen it as a logial NOT in logic classes such as NOT A THEN B is represented as ~A --> B instead of the symbol '¬'.

Comment: The diaeresis can also be used with i, but it is a marginal use. In poetry and the like, it is used to force a hiatus on what otherwise would be a diptong.

Comment: @MikMik Qué interesante.  No lo sabía.  ¿Tienes alguna referencia?

Comment: Check diéresis [in the RAE dictionary](http://lema.rae.es/drae/?val=di%C3%A9resis) or [in the DPD](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=di%C3%A9resis). Actually, it seems that it goes on the first vowel of the diphthong to be "broken", so I guess it can be any vowel. In the links, there are examples on i (vïuda) and u (rüido, süave).

Comment: Nice to know, but I have lived in Spain for over twenty five years (including school years) and never, ever encountered a diéresis other than the u (ü) one. The examples you use, are used with out diéresis in the day to day spanish. How strange, maybe some old linguistic deprecated rules? Edit: ah! I followed the links and are only used in old poetry texts. Now I understand :)

Answer (score 0):

^ is used in Math syntax for powers: 3^2=9, because of the difficulty of writing it on the computer with its traditional notation. It's an international unwritten law (or maybe written), so we also need it.

The same with ~, it means an approximation in Maths. Also negation in logic syntax.

In Spanish language there is no usage of `, but (I'm not sure about this) I think Catalan language does use it, and they use our same keyboard. It's also useful for writing in French or Italian.

So, although they aren't used on Spanish language, <strike>they aren't dead keys for us.</strike>

Comment: "Dead keys" means that "it does not generate a (complete) character by itself but modifies the character generated by the key struck immediately after" [ref](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_key)

Comment: Oh, I didn't know it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The tilde is occasionally used with the letter "a" in Portuguese.  e. g. sao paolo.
(sorry, I can't type it correctly, but there is a tilde on the first "a").